# Gesture Detection with more Items android

Tags: android, android-layout, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, gesture-recognition

In my application, I save data in my sqlite db a variable number of notes composed of: `(IDNote,title,body, date of creation, owner of note, icon_name)`. When i save and query the DB, my data are all ok, so my question is, Is possible to implement GestureDetection for moving and restore a single icon that correspond at a single note ? Because a found an example but all the icons are moved, but i want to move only one icon at time simulating all the gesture of the icons of Desktop computer. 
Thanks in advance.
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set an OnTouchListener on the view that holds your icon. This listener is called when an ACTION_DOWN event on the view is caught.
2. Here register it somewhere as the 'currently dragged object'. Make sure onTouch() returns false, so the event is propagated further to your views parent.
3. This parent is responsible for checking whether a view has been registered as the 'currently dragged object'. Also, it has to call your Gesturedetector, which in onScroll will do the actual scrolling and moving.

This is just an idea, tell how it went!

Comment: Hi Bondax, thanks for your reply!! this procedure could be good but you have some code example or tutorial or link to follow?? thanks